# What is the difference between conditional logit fixed effect model and logit model?

Tags: logistic, panel-data, cross-section, clogit, multinomial-logit

I have a binary dependent variable and about 10 covariates. My dependent variable is whether a child under 5 years of age has ARI or not. I am using a DHS survey for data. Most other papers use simple logistic regression but I want to control or the unobserved heterogeneity among different districts so can I use conditional logit fixed effect model for this? I do not have panel data. It is a cross-section data. So would a conditional logit fixed effect model be okay to use?